# Yahoo Query Language - RSS

Tags: javascript, rss, yql

```
var site = 'www.mysite.com/news.aspx?rss=1';
var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from xml where url="' + site + '"') + '&format=xml';
$.get(yql).done(function (rss)
{
         //do the Things
}
```

Currently I have this function trying to load external site RSS feed.  Unfortunately it is not loading the feed correctly so I cannot do the Things.  This feed was loading correctly using the Google Feeds Api, but as that is being depracated soon I am trying to move to a different method of RSS loading in Javascript (Cross-Domain).  Is there something I am doing incorrectly with the YQL url?

```
        error="Redirected to a robots.txt restricted URL: http(s)://www.mySite.com/news.aspx?rss=1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following URL mapping as a test:

```
'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from xml where url="http://www.bls.gov/feed/empsit.rss"')
```

which generates a valid YQL query:

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bls.gov%2Ffeed%2Fempsit.rss%22
```

with the following JSON alternate output:

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bls.gov%2Ffeed%2Fempsit.rss%22&format=json
```

and keep the following restrictions in mind to troubleshoot:

> YQL uses the robots.txt file on your server to determine the Web pages accessible from your site. YQL uses the user-agent "Yahoo Pipes 2.0" when accessing the robots.txt file and checks it for allows/disallows from this user agent. If the robots.txt check does prevent YQL from accessing your content, it will then fetch the target page using a different user agent:

Therefore, to allow YQL access to your content, simply add "Yahoo Pipes 2.0" to the relevent parts of your robots.txt. For example:

```
User-agent: Yahoo Pipes 2.0
Allow: /
```

**References**

- [Widgetbox, YQL, and Pipes](https://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/widgetbox-yql-pipes-8016.html)
- [YQL Guide: Limiting Access to Content Provider Data](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/overview.html#limiting-access)
- [HTML 4.0 Specification, Appendix B: Search robots](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/appendix/notes.html#h-B.4.1)
- [Stackoverflow.com robots.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt)
- [Revisiting My Classic ASP and URL Rewrite for Dynamic SEO Functionality Examples](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robert_mcmurray/archive/2013/11/20/revisiting-my-classic-asp-and-url-rewrite-for-dynamic-seo-functionality-examples.aspx)